Rocketchat workspace registration for 6.5.0 and later
For Rocketchat version 6.5.0 and later, I have read that workspace registration is required.
But after registering the workspace, the domain name of the rocketchat instance will be shown in rocketchat cloud. Is it possible to register workspace without the domain name? Or perhaps bypass this workspace registration so that I can continue to use rc?
Thanks!
